# HttpPost special characters arent sended

Tags: android

I use the following code to send data to my server:

```
public InputStream getStreamFromConnection(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    if(ConnectionDetector.isConnectedToInternet(this.context)) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        return httpEntity.getContent();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When i now have a message in my params which looks like that:

```
The leadership earned 1000$ during the last years.
```

The server receives:

```
The leadership earned 1000
```

And all of the messages are cut exactly at the index of any special character.
And even more. if somone writes a message with a smile like:

```
:)
```

This arrives at the server

```
??
```

How can i send the special characters and smielies to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just have to encode your URL before you execute a request with it.
Try encoding your URL like this:

```
String encodedUrl = URLEncodedUtils.format(urlWithParameters, "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have before your special characters this   `\\`?
because without it the server won't understand it.

(Sorry I couldn't leave a comment due to reputation)